# Drawing a shape without XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

Hi I am trying to draw a simple shape of rectangle in a middle of my screen. Unfortunately all the tutorials I found online tells me how to do it in XAML. The one tutorial I found tells me how to draw rectangle in a windows form

```
System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(50, 100, 150, 150);

graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
```

however this does not work inside Universal app. Is there an analog of something like this for Universal app? Thank you very much

Comment: Whats wrong with XAML? Thats pretty much the standard for Windows 10 apps.

Comment: I am pretty new to Windows dev and it feels like the XAML is very static. if I want my shape to appear and move around for a simple 2d game XAML wouldnt work

Comment: Clearly you haven't gotten to animations yet :) There are plenty of ways to move elements around in XAML, though if you are doing this *enough*, then DirectX is more efficent.

Comment: do you have any links to a xaml shapes anymation tutorial?

Comment: You animate like anything else, with a `Storyboard` modifying a `TranslateTransform`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756779(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, not really.

In Windows Universal Apps you have 3 main choices to draw something on the screen:

1- You can use XAML components as you have seen already, you can [create such components programmatically as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406239/how-to-programatically-create-a-xaml-panel-with-controls) and [create animations with them](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-28-Working-with-Animations-in-XAML).

2- You can create an [HTML/Javascript-based application](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/developing-universal-windows-apps-with-html-and-javascript-jump-start-8344?l=qWp1uOEz_3204984382)

3- You can [use a XAML control as a raw canvas and draw graphics on it using DirectX/DirectWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991975.aspx), but you may need to use C++ for doing the actual drawing.

Comment: I am pretty new to Windows dev and it feels like the XAML is very static. if I want my shape to appear and move around for a simple 2d game XAML wouldnt work

Comment: @user5309974 In that case I am afraid [you may need to use DirectX and C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452744.aspx)

Comment: Mostly true, if you only have a few elements moving, then simple XAML animations would suffice.

Comment: @user5309974 XAML is not "static" in any way. You can animate stuff using the animations API, or you can even just bind your UI elements' properties to a data item and have a timer change the data items' properties.

Comment: @yms your suggestion about "creating UI elements programatically" is also wrong. In WPF/UWP/XAML, you will use an `ItemsControl` and DataTemplates instead of procedurally manipulating the UI, regardless of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @yms please show me one (1) use case where you will want to procedurally manipulate the UI in XAML based technologies, as opposed to using proper XAML and databinding, please.